# Why dwa planner can't reach the target rotation?

Tags: ros, navigation, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've commanded the robot to go to the green arrow position/rotation, so it went there and started rotating CCW until it got near the upper wall, then it got stuck in that position.
The question is why it don't go a bit forward so it can complete the rotation? Which parameters can be changed so that it better behave in situations like that?

[image: image description]

Update:
It keeps writing in the logs:

> [ INFO] [1501263591.230230037]: Got
> new plan [ WARN]
> [1501263591.260831641]: Invalid
> Trajectory 0.000000, 0.000000,
> 0.150000, cost: -6.000000 [ WARN] [1501263591.260927725]: Rotation cmd
> in collision [ INFO]
> [1501263591.260981225]: Error when
> rotating.

and after some seconds:

> [ERROR] [1501263591.331646239]:
> Aborting because a valid control could
> not be found. Even after executing all
> recovery behaviors

Currently we have recovery_behavior_enabled = true and clearing_rotation_allowed = false

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267526/why-dwa-planner-can%27t-reach-the-target-rotation?/) by [Vitor](https://answers.ros.org/users/29650/vitor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-07-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-28**:
What's the output at the terminal?

**Comment by [Vitor](https://answers.ros.org/users/29650/vitor/) on 2017-07-28**:
@jayess I've updated the question with console output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe it's because you have the `clearing_rotation_allowed` parameter set to `false`. It won't rotate to clear the cost map and replan, it'll just give up like you're seeing.

From [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Parameters), the `clearing_rotation_allowed` parameter

> Determines whether or not the robot
> will attempt an in-place rotation when
> attempting to clear out space. Note:
> This parameter is only used when the
> default recovery behaviors are in use,
> meaning the user has not set the
> recovery_behaviors parameter to
> anything custom.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vitor](https://answers.ros.org/users/29650/vitor/) on 2017-07-31**:
I'll try to enable that, but that behavior has given me problems in the past (like colliding with walls). However, I can't understand why it can't finish the move without resorting to the recovery behaviors, as it would be a simple movement to get out of there